# Why do I have to set the int_input to none?

Tags: python

I am new to coding, and my brother helped me write the following code. I was having a hard time understanding why you have to make the "int_input = none", and then later say "if int_input is not None" Thanks so much for your time!

````
name = input('What is your name: ' )
int_input = None
string_or_number = input(' Do you want to type in a string or a number? ' )
if string_or_number.upper() == 'NUMBER':
    int_input = int(input(' on a scale of 1-10, how happy are you? ' ))
else:  
    string_input = (input( 'Are you happy or sad? ' ))
if int_input is not None:
    if int_input > 5:
        print("I'm glad to hear you are feeling a " + str(int_input) + ' out of 10')
    elif int_input <=5:
        print("I'm sorry to hear you are feeling a " + str(int_input) + ' out of 10')
else: 
        if string_input.upper() == 'HAPPY':
            print('I am glad you are ' + string_input)
        elif string_input.upper() != 'HAPPY':
            print('That is too bad ' + name) ```
````

Comment: It defines the name `int_input`. Otherwise you would get a `NameError` because the Python interpreter wouldn't know what it was.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise `int_input` because of the `if` statement that follows it.

Let's imagine that you didn't initialise `int_input`. Then if `string_or_number.upper()` is not equal to `'NUMBER'`, then the variable `int_input` will never be initialised. So when you're trying to access it in the next if statement i.e. `if int_input > 5:`, `int_input` will not have a value, which will cause the python interpreter to throw a `NameError`, causing the code to crash.

Answer (score 1):

EL15:
By setting `int_input` as `None` it gives you a way to check whether or not the input from the user is accepted or if it is correct or not ( in your case if it's equal to `NUMBER`). For example, if a user doesn't input anything or inputs something wrong , then the default value of int_input is `None` and remains unchanged, and hence the code inside `if int_input is not None:` won't run and instead, the code inside `else` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, which explains very well why you had to initialize the variable in your code; here is a different version of your code where you don't need to initialize this variable, which I now call `hapiness_var` and which can be either a string or an int; but will always be defined after the inputs.

```
# Input name, remove head/trailing spaces, and turn the first letter into a capital letter.
name = input('What is your name: ' ).strip().capitalize()
# Ask if string or number, remove head/trailing spaces, and then turn into upper cases.
string_or_number = input(' Do you want to type in a string or a number? ' ).strip().upper()

if string_or_number.upper() == 'NUMBER':
    hapiness_var = int(input(' on a scale of 1-10, how happy are you? ' ))
else:
    hapiness_var = input( 'Are you happy or sad? ' ).strip().upper()
    
# Try/except to do see if it's a string or an int.
# If it's a string, the if test will fail, and the program will switch to the
# except clause
try:
    if hapiness_var > 5:
        print (f"I'm glad to hear you are feeling a {hapiness_var} out of 10")
    elif hapiness_var <= 5:
        print("I'm sorry to hear you are feeling a {hapiness_var} out of 10")
except:
    if string_input.upper() == 'HAPPY':
        print('I am glad you are ' + hapiness_var)
    elif string_input.upper() != 'HAPPY':
        print('That is too bad ' + name)
```